# Anything in iPhone that resembles Android ArrayList

Tags: ios, arraylist, mapping

I am from android background and I just started working on iPhone 
I want to perform this operation in iPhone as I do in Android.

```
ArrayList<String> aa = new ArrayList<String>();

public void fillArray(String s)
{
    aa.add(s);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **Binyamin Sharet** suggest you have to use `NSMutableArray`. This class allows you to create a dynamic array. You can perform addition or deletion. On the contrary `NSArray` is a immutable version of it. You cannot add or delete objects to a `NSArray` once created.

The same distinction can be applied to `NSDictionary` and `NSMutableDictionary` (and other).

Here a simple example.

```
NSMutableArray* arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[arr addObject:@"first string"];
[arr addObject:@"second string"];
```

An important aspect of `NSMutableArray` (the same could be applied to other class) is the memory management one. When you add an object to a `NSMutableArray` it retains objects added to it. So, if you **NOT** use ARC you have to deal with this aspect.

```
NSMutableArray* arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
id obj = [[NSObject alloc] init]; // a general object
[arr addObject:obj];

[obj release];
```

For further info I suggest you to read about [NSMutableArray class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Hope it helps.